# Is PHP7 a static or dynamic typed language?

Tags: php

In the past few years, we've been using dynamically typed versions of PHP. However, in PHP7 we have an option to enable 'strict types':

- [PHP RFC: Return Type Declarations](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/return_types)
- [PHP RFC: Scalar Type Declarations](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/scalar_type_hints_v5)

(Note: Scalar Type Declarations repeatedly uses the phrase "weak type checking" or "strictly typed" versus static/dynamic.)

Is it right to say that PHP7 is a statically typed language? If so or not, why?

Comment: I don't think you can call a language strongly typed if variables don't have a type.

Comment: The phrases "strongly typed" and "weakly typed" are not well-defined. As such it is not possible to answer such a question for any language.

Comment: @Darkhogg I partially do agree, however, if you have worked with PHP7, you might have also stumbled across strict types for methods, etc which is what makes me think.

Comment: @Jules strongly typed languages are ones that require casting or conversion while weakly typed languages do coercion.

Comment: That is one possible definition. There are several others for each such phrase. You should use more exact terms, and avoid the strong/weak ambiguity.

Comment: @Jules The context is programming so it is pretty obvious.

Comment: @HassanAlthaf Whether you like it or not, Jules is right. The definition of strongly/weakly typed is subjective. For example, is Java strongly types? Most people say yes, but a Haskell programer might not.

Comment: Not really, no. see the top answer at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/38002/what-arguments-are-there-in-favor-of-weak-typing or [this excellent blog post](http://ericlippert.com/2012/10/15/is-c-a-strongly-typed-or-a-weakly-typed-language/) by Eric Lippert for more detail.

Comment: @Darkhogg Well, I understand that each and every theory cannot be implemented practically completely, but it is always possible to do so partially.

Comment: Without a definition of the terms "strong" and "weak" typing, this question is meaningless and un-answerable.

Comment: @JörgWMittag If you bothered reading the comments, you would've found an answer. Also, then, how otherwise would Scant Roger answer this?

Comment: Comments are ephemeral. They can (and will be) deleted for lots of different reasons. If it isn't in the question, it doesn't exist. I could probably name about 15 different, incompatible, conflicting definitions of those terms off the top of my head, all of which are in widespread use. Note that Scant Roger *doesn't* answer the question about strong/weak typing. He even explicitly says so. He answers a *different* question about static/dynamic typing.

Comment: @HassanAlthaf this question is meaningless and rightly closed and in the future deleted. The fact that it has answers doesn't make it less meaningless.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As mentioned, ["strong" and "weak" type systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#.22Strong.22_and_.22weak.22_type_systems) are ill-defined:

> 'Languages are often colloquially referred to as "strongly typed" or
>   "weakly typed". In fact, there is no universally accepted definition
>   of what these terms mean. In general, there are more precise terms to
>   represent the differences between type systems that lead people to
>   call them "strong" or "weak"'.

[Static types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_type-checking) can be verified at compile time. The compiler has enough information to verify static types before a program runs. (If a typed variable is used where the type is not expected, it's a compiler error.) [Dynamic types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Dynamic_type-checking_and_runtime_type_information) *cannot* be perfectly determined at compile time. This doesn't mean variables in dynamic languages don't have types. It just means there's no way to be 100% certain of a variable's type until run-time.

According to the PHP RFCs for [return type declaration](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/return_types) and [scalar type declaration](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/scalar_type_hints_v5), non-typed declarations and evaluation modes are still allowed. This means not all of PHP is statically typed. As such, it doesn't make sense to call PHP a statically typed language. Instead, it's a dynamically typed language with a couple static type features.

The fact that the scalar type declaration RFC actually uses the definitions "strict" and "weak" type checking is telling. The PHP folks pride themselves on *not* being language nerds. This is neither good nor bad. It just means the language designers are focusing on different things than, say, Haskell designers.

Comment: A dynamically typed language with optional static annotations is also frequently called [*gradually typed*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradual_typing). It's a current trend in “scripting” languages that want to offer more static safety or better performance, but also in static languages that want to offer a more scripty feel (notably, C#).